# How can I rename a file in Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have an app which randomly shows user 2 pictures and lets them pick the better one. I want to rate the images through an algorithm and rename those files according to their updated rating. So how can I rename a file in Firebase Storage?

**If anyone has a better solution for my problem, please comment down on the question.**

Comment: The Firebase client libraries do not provide a way to rename a file. You can instead copy the file to a new location and delete the original.

Comment: can I write metadata?

Comment: Sure. You can specify custom metadata using the `setCustomMetadata()` method, as explained on the [relevant section of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata#custom_metadata).